# In what data type we can save fingerprint data in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, fingerprint, sqldatatypes

In what data type we can save fingerprint data in a mysql database ?

Comment: it depends on the size of your fingerprint

Comment: what data ur getting from scanner. you can store it a hash value in string or gif images as blob values;

Comment: Save it as BLOB type : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-save-a-fingerprint-in-MySQL-database-with-PHP